# Does ARRAY_SIZE return undefined behaviour when the array is empty?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

Is ARRAY_SIZE return undefined behaviour when the array is empty? because we make a devide of unexisting `sizeof((X)[0])`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef ARRAY_SIZE
#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) sizeof((X))/sizeof((X)[0])
#endif

struct ka {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct ka k[] = {};
    printf("%d\n", ARRAY_SIZE(k));
}
```

Comment: This is not C++. Empty initializer is forbidden for array with unspecified bound

Comment: This is not UB since `sizeof(k[0])` does not actually access any memory. It is exactly the same as `sizeof(ka)`

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to have zero-sized arrays in Standard C or C++.

In C your code is a constraint violation (empty initializer lists are not permitted anywhere).

In C++ it is also an error; `{}` may not be used with an array definition that omits the size. (C++14 [dcl.init.aggr]/4)

If you use a non-standard compiler extension then the behaviour will depend on the details of that extension.

Comment: I build with gcc and it does not return error for C neither a warning

Comment: Why is it a divide by zero error? `sizeof((X)[0])` is `sizeof(struct ka)`, which is not `0`.

Comment: @MOHAMED gcc defaults to GNU extensions mode.  Use compile switches `-std=c11 -pedantic` for C, or `std=c++14 -pedantic` for C++ to get standard behaviour.

Comment: @mch good point ... fixed

Answer (score 1):

In general, from the point of view for memory access, this is fine, because, unless the operand of `sizeof` is of VLA type, they are **not** evaluated. So, in this case, `x[0]` is not an invalid memory access.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4, *emphasis mine*

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; **otherwise, the operand is not evaluated** and the result is an
>   integer constant.

In a broad sense, for an array like

```
 int arr[5]= {0};
```

writing

```
 sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[10]);
```

is also *valid* as `arr[10]` is not being evaluated, it's only about the size of the operand, not the *content* (so, needs no dereferencing).

That said,

- zero-length arrays are not standard C, they are [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).
- `sizeof` yields a results of size `size_t`, so we should use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

Comment: What does being evaluated have to do with it

Comment: @M.M dereferencing invalid memory?

Comment: Oh I see, He was concerned that x[0] might be an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: In my case the ARRAY_SIZE return a garbage value instead of 0! Why?

Comment: @MOHAMED even after `zu`?

Comment: with `zu` works fine. what is the risk to get garbage if I assign it to int. I mean `int x = ARRAY_SIZE(K)`. Are there a risk to get garbage value in `x` ?

Comment: @MOHAMED well, there's risk. `size_t` is defined to to be unsigned integer type, it's not the same as `int` or even `unsigned int`. It can very well be `unsigned long long` which may not fit into a `unsigned int` for that platform. Stick to `%zu`, for better.